# "The connection was reset" in localhost:8000 using django and docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

After running `docker-compose up`,

> Starting docker_django ... done
>
> Attaching to docker_django
>
> docker_django | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
>
> docker_django | Performing system checks...
>
> docker_django | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> docker_django | February 12, 2020 - 07:26:35
>
> docker_django | Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'backend.settings'
>
> docker_django | Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>
> docker_django | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

when i connect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ it shows this
[image]
There is no problem / error running the docker-compose command but only when visiting the site.

Im using ubuntu 19.10 and the project has django v3.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        container_name: docker_django
        command: python manage.py runserver
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your application only listens to requests coming from localhost, which in case of a container are requests coming from inside the container.

Try this compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        container_name: docker_django
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

*corrected typo for port number as suggested*

Comment: Ow thanks, it works. Just need to change `0.0.0.0:8080` to `0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: This also works for php built-in web server, problem solved after running `php -S 0.0.0.0:5001`

Answer (score -2):

What ended up working for me was:

1. Stopping all docker instance
2. Opening a command prompt in admin mode
3. Executing the command 'netsh winsock reset'
4. Restarting the machine
5. Restarting docker containers