# Can't access python web service in docker container

Tags: python, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a python web service and it simply replies on redis, for which I want to create a dev env using docker, it showed the build process was successful but I can't access the page on my host locally.

My dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config libpq-dev

RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

WORKDIR /code/mo_backend

COPY . .

RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install -r requirements.txt

# EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Compose file is

```
services:
  mo_backend:
    build:
      context: .
      ssh:
        - default
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.7
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

After I ran `docker compose up`, it showed
[service started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMktR.png)

But when I tried to visit the 8000 port, it was empty.

I tried localhost:8000, 127.0.0.1:8000, 0.0.0.0:8000, neither of them worked

Im using WSL, tried to access the site on my windows host locally.

Comment: What HTTPcode did you get when calling it? "Empty" could mean that you successfully reach the server but not the right path. Are you sure your code listens on port 8000? Did you try to exec in the container and use curl to debug?

Comment: Do you need to tell the Django server to listen on 0.0.0.0, as in ["The connection was reset" in localhost:8000 using django and docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183313/the-connection-was-reset-in-localhost8000-using-django-and-docker)?  (Change your Dockerfile `CMD`, don't put an override `command:` in the Compose file.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thx it works
BTW may I know the difference here between 127.0.0.1 vs 0.0.0.0?
I did some search and seems 127.0.0.1 is the address that you can only visit on the same machine, so based on virtualization of the container, it was treated as another machine. Please correct me if Im wrong
What about 0.0.0.0 then? Why can I visit this address through this? If I run the service locally, I can't really tell the  difference, cuz both of them works

Comment: See [Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip).  Since Docker provides each container with an isolated network environment, 127.0.0.1 is the container-private localhost interface.

Answer (score 0):

The line exposing the port is a comment. Remove the # in

```
# EXPOSE 8000
```

Is it enough ?

Comment: `EXPOSE` doesn't really actually do anything in modern Docker, so uncommenting this line shouldn't matter.

Comment: You're right, I thought it was doing something. It is stated [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) in the docs.