# Django server not accessible when run through docker-compose: connection reset by peer

Tags: django, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a docker image which runs django. Docker-compose is like this:

```
services:
  www:
    image: my-www-image
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

If I `docker exec -ti bash` into this container and `curl localhost`, I get Django-related output, and the docker-compose log notes the GET request.

If I go to the host machine and `curl localhost`, I get

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

(note this is not a Connection refused, which I would get if I use a random wrong port number)

Adding `EXPOSE 80` to the Dockerfile made no difference.

Why can't the host machine connect to the otherwise-working service inside the container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The connection was reset" in localhost:8000 using django and docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183313/the-connection-was-reset-in-localhost8000-using-django-and-docker)